# Huawei E303 USB modem not working in 14.04

Tags: usb, usb-modem, modem-manager

I installed Ubuntu on my pen drive. I can connect using my android phone tethering, but when I wanted to use my Huawei Mobile 3G USB modem, it is not detected by Ubuntu but shows a CD ROM type of icon on launcher.

How to get the USB modem running?

Answer (score 0):

You must "eject" the CD to make the modem to function. 
You can eject it from terminal or disks or launcher.
It will then detected as modem.
You can find it network manager.